# Ubuntu, boots to black screen

Tags: boot, nvidia, recovery-mode

**Stuck at this screen ( dev nvme0n1 clean build)**

Hey I just started to dual boot Ubuntu on my laptop that has NVIDIA rtx 2060, I'm currently stuck on this screen, anyone that can guide me through this? thanks in advance.

[image: Early boot message, from fsck]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Assumption: You successfully installed Ubuntu, now getting "a black screen" when attempting a boot.*

Hit ESC once at the moment the BIOS displays disappears - do you get "grub menu"? If yes, check for "Recovery mode":

In the recovery mode menu:

- select the "fsck" option to enable write mode for your main disk,
- select "start network" to enable the use of `apt install ...` *(which retrieves programs from the net)* in a root shell.
- Finally drop to (enable, start) a "root shell"; *you will need and extra `ENTER` to get to it.*

**What the ACTUAL problem is might be revealed by this:**
At the root prompt begin with `dmesg | less` and start reading from the end backwards (hit `>` and then up arrow, also: `h` will display the viewer options at that stage).

Add text to your question (edit!) to tell what you see - if you cannot get forward on your own (google?).

**I would guess you need some form of nvidia driver.**
Type:
`$ apt install nvidia-driver-` then hit TAB (twice?) ... and a load of stuff named nvidia-driver- will appear.

Pick the simplest name, probably with a version number in it (try picking the largest) and complete the name for it (type first or a few characters, hit TAB to "complete" it, completion stops at a point where there are more than one option, type more and hit TAB again...).
When a space appears, you have one selected a package, then hit `enter` to start the install.

Note: That is my GUESS what you need to do. This MIGHT be wrong though, depending on your findings with dmesg above.

Comment: *NOTE: All from memory, not checked for actual names and text on Ubuntus after 16.04.*

Comment: Thx man it worked

Comment: Have a nice day champ

Comment: nice...  Welcome to askubuntu.com! In case you find an answer to help solve a problem don't forget to click either the grey ☑ or the up-pointing arrow/triangle to the left of the text.

Comment: Thanks, done now!